# Accepting variable number of arguments for logger

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I don't know if this can be achieved through variadic template, variadic marcos or even maybe metaprogramming.

Basically I have a logging object like this:

```
LOG << "This is the value of variable X: " << varaibleX;
```

but I also want this to be able to use `LOG` like a function

```
LOG ( "This is the value of variable X: ", variableX);
```

but the number of argument can be varying. (assuming they call can be converted into streams)

I was looking at `LOG ( ... )`, but really not sure how to expand the arguments.

So let's say someone wrote

```
LOG(X, Y, Z);
```

and I want to expand this into:

```
LOG << X << Y << Z;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: How about `LOG("Blargh: " << X << Y << Z)`? Single argument, and `LOG` just expands that behind whatever you're logging with. Also, check out http://www.templog.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with variadic templates like below.  Since its not clear what your LOG object is, I omitted the code to actually call LOG(...), but you should be able to port this do what you need:

```
#include <iostream>

/**
 * A specialization to stream the last argument 
 * and terminate the recursion. 
 */
template<typename Stream, typename Arg1>
Stream & DoLog(Stream & stream, const Arg1 & arg1)
{
   return (stream << arg1);
}

/** 
 * Recursive function to keep streaming the arguments 
 * one at a time until the last argument is reached and 
 * the specialization above is called. 
 */
template<typename Stream, typename Arg1, typename... Args>
Stream & DoLog(Stream & stream, const Arg1 & arg1, const Args&... args)
{
   return DoLog((stream << arg1), args...);
}

int main()
{
   DoLog(std::cout, "First ", 5, 6) << " Last" << std::endl;
}
```

You'll need to compile this with *c++0x* support.  With g++, this can be done using the **--std=c++0x** flag.

Comment: Yeah, I think this would work. So the logging function would be turned into a recursive function call, right?